# How to improve speed of a correlated sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a correlated sub-query that I need to add many more sub-queries to. I know so far this route results in a slow query. How else can I approach this problem?

```
select

  c.TRANSDATE as Transdate,

  lag(sum(convert(float,c.AMOUNTMST-c.SETTLEAMOUNTMST)),1) over(order by c.TRANSDATE) as "Beginning 
Balance",

    (( select top 1 sum(convert(float,c2.AMOUNTMST-c2.SETTLEAMOUNTMST))
      from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c2
      where c2.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'ACT Payment' and c2.TransType2 = 'Customer' and c2.TRANSDATE 
= c.TRANSDATE
      group by c2.TRANSDATE
    ))as "FTI-ACT Payment",

    (( select top 1 sum(convert(float,c3.AMOUNTMST-c3.SETTLEAMOUNTMST))
      from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c3
      where c3.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Bulk' and c3.TransType2 = 'Customer' and c3.TRANSDATE = 
c.TRANSDATE
      group by c3.TRANSDATE
    ))as "FTI-Bulk",
  sum(convert(float,c.AMOUNTMST-c.SETTLEAMOUNTMST)) as "Actual Ending Balance"
from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c
group by c.TRANSDATE
order by c.TRANSDATE
```

Result:

```
Transdate       Beginning Balance       FTI-ACT Payment     FTI-Bulk        Actual Ending Balance
2019-04-12              NULL                  NULL            NULL                -22591.47
2019-04-15             -22591.47              599.69          NULL                 -394.95
2019-04-25             -394.95                NULL            2539.57              -1776
2019-04-26             -1776                  NULL            NULL                 -11973.84
```

Comment: Don't have the time to really go through all of this, but a quick glance shows you are connected to the same table twice: two separated correlated sub queries. You might be able to improve this by using a JOIN and conditional aggregation instead, or maybe a lateral join (APPLY) operation instead, so you only need to look at the additional table once.

Comment: Changed my mind, there's an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a two options:

First, JOIN + conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    c.TRANSDATE as Transdate,
    lag(sum(convert(float,c.AMOUNTMST-c.SETTLEAMOUNTMST)),1) over(order by c.TRANSDATE) as [Beginning Balance],
    sum(case when c2.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'ACT Payment' THEN convert(float,c2.AMOUNTMST-c2.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) ELSE 0 END) AS [FTI-ACT Payment],
    sum(case when c2.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Bulk' THEN convert(float,c2.AMOUNTMST-c2.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-Bulk],
    sum(convert(float,c.AMOUNTMST-c.SETTLEAMOUNTMST)) as [Actual Ending Balance]
FROM[AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c
LEFT JOIN [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c2 ON c2.TRANSDATE = c.TRANSDATE AND c2.TransType2 = 'Customer'
GROUP BY c.TRANSDATE
ORDER BY c.TRANSDATE
```

Or lateral join + conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    c.TRANSDATE as Transdate,
    lag(sum(convert(float,c.AMOUNTMST-c.SETTLEAMOUNTMST)),1) over(order by c.TRANSDATE) as [Beginning Balance],
    c2.[FTI-ACT Payment], c2.[FTI-Bulk],
    sum(convert(float,c.AMOUNTMST-c.SETTLEAMOUNTMST)) as [Actual Ending Balance]
FROM[AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 
        sum(case when c2.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'ACT Payment' THEN convert(float,c2.AMOUNTMST-c2.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) ELSE 0 END) AS [FTI-ACT Payment],
        sum(case when c2.BILLINGCLASSIFICATION = 'Bulk' THEN convert(float,c3.AMOUNTMST-c3.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) ELSE 0 END) As [FTI-Bulk]
    FROM [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] c2
    WHERE c2.TRANSDATE = c.TRANSDATE AND c2.TransType2 = 'Customer'
    GROUP BY c2.TRANSDATE
) c2
GROUP BY c.TRANSDATE
ORDER BY c.TRANSDATE
```

Probably the first will do a little better, but both should at least get you from two extra passes through the table for each row down to one. These will especially help if you have an index on the table including both the `TransType2` and `TransDate` columns in the same index, in that order. Even better if this index also has `BILLINGCLASSIFICATION`, `AMOUNTMST`, and `SETTLEAMOUNTMST` in the `INCLUDE` section. That will allow the JOIN/APPLY to operate entirely out of the index. Possibly also do just a [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) for the `Customer` value in `TransType2`.

While I'm here, I also need to question whether `float` is adequate for dealing with money values. You probably want `decimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can benefit from the composite index:

```
create index ix1 on [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V] 
  (BILLINGCLASSIFICATION, TransType2, TRANSDATE);
```